# Draggable and resizable in JqueryUI for an image is not working?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-resizable

I used below code for dragging and resizing the image,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>

        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $( "#img_content" ).draggable().resizable();

    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body class='default'>       


<div class="demo">
<!--<div id="img_content" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>-->

<img id="img_content" class="ui-widget-content" src="Tulips.jpg" />

</div>


    </body>
</html>
```

resizable is working corretly. but dragging the image not working. if i applied for div structure

```
<div id="img_content" class="ui-widget-content">
        <p>Drag me around</p>
    </div>
```

its working fine.

How do i implement drag and resize for image tag?

Comment: Take a look at this http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4241

Answer (score 11):

You should **wrap the image into a div** with `style="display:inline-block;` and then make the div draggable and the image resizable.
[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/8VY52/)

Answer (score 3):

The solution I've found was resizing/making dragable a  with a background image. I guess that the  element is not draggable and resizable.
Well, it works for me.
Bye.

Comment: Please could you try to rephrase that? I have a hard time understanding I'm afraid.