# Resize Image in WYSIWYG HTML Editor

Tags: tinymce, devexpress, wysiwyg, html-editor

I am creating a WYSIWYG HTML editor using DevExpress' HTML Editor.

I would like to allow end-users to upload an image and resize the image inside the editor using handles on each corner (I basically want to copy the functionality of [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/)). I would also like the image to be insertable into paragraphs (so that it can be inline with text) and allow it to be dragged around into different locations in paragraphs.  However, I can't get it working all that well.

My first thought is to use jQuery UI's Resizable method.  [Here is what I have created so far](https://jsfiddle.net/wyeack/6y92p28L/3/):

#### JavaScript

```
$(".child").resizable({
    aspectRatio:true,   
    minWidth:100,                    
    maxWidth:$(".parent").width(),                  
    containment:"parent",
    handles:"ne,nw,se,sw",
    resize: function( event, ui ) {
    var topB = (parseInt($(this).css("top")) > 0)
        ? parseInt($(this).css("top")) : 3;
    var leftB = (parseInt($(this).css("left")) > 0)
        ? parseInt($(this).css("left")) : 3;
    if (parseInt($(this).css("left"))< 3)
    {
        $(this).trigger('mouseup'); 
        $(this).css({"left":leftB+"px","top":topB+"px"});
    }
    if (parseInt($(this).css("top"))< 3)
    {
        $(this).trigger('mouseup'); 
        $(this).css({"left":leftB+"px","top":topB+"px"});}
    }}).draggable({ containment: "parent" });
```

#### CSS

```
.container { margin:40px; }

.parent
{
    background: yellow;
    width: 250px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    padding:5px;
}

.child
{
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 80px;
    position:absolute;
}

.child img
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.ui-resizable-ne,
.ui-resizable-se,
.ui-resizable-nw,
.ui-resizable-sw
{
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 9px !important;
    height: 9px !important;
}

.ui-resizable-se
{
    background-image: none !important;
    right: -5px !important;
    bottom: -5px !important;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="parent">      
        <img class="child" src="https://yeackstorage.blob.core.windows.net/yeackwebsitecontent/Content/Files/1607150ECE1959FE17438494AEADCF39CAECD0.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here are the issues that I am having:

1. The resizing squares are only partially visible.
2. When I put it inside of a paragraph, it does not behave well.
3. According to [some other answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703450/draggable-and-resizable-in-jqueryui-for-an-image-is-not-working), jQuery's resizable() works best when the  is wrapped in a .  However, this would make it unable to be contained inside of a paragraph, correct?  Also - TinyMCE seems to be able to accomplish this without wrapping the image in a div.

This seems like it should be simple functionality to implement - is there a simpler way to go about it? If jQuery's resizable is the best option, how would I be able to make it work correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The DevExpress ASPxHtmlEditor uses the built-in browser's content editable functionality for this purpose. While it is available out-of-the-box in the MS-based browsers, it may not work in the others. Play, for example, [this demo](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxHtmlEditorDemos/Features/General.aspx) to test how it works.

As an universal image resizing functionality, it is recommended using its Insert/Change Image Dialog instead. Play, for example, [this demo](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxHtmlEditorDemos/Dialogs/ImageSelector.aspx) to learn more on how to use it.

Comment: I think that having to invoke a dialog is a very clunky way of resizing images.  Many of the other WYSIWYG editor have implemented strong client-side resizing functionality - especially Froala and TinyMCE.  This functionality allows you to resize in a consistent manner across all browsers...